# Clase para manejo de sesiones dejó de funcionar en php 7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, session

Hace tiempo la uso para manejar sesiones en aplicaciones pero hace unos días se cambio a php 7.2 y ya no funciona. No pude encontrar cuál es el error ya que simplemente no se loguea y me envía siempre al login, lo que se que no hace es guardar la info de la sesión en la tabla por ende es como si no existiera, alguna idea?

Calculo que el problema es la versión de php, pero no pude encontrar nada para corregirla o hacer una nueva con las características que pide php 7

La clase

```
class MySqlSessionHandler
{
    protected $dbConnection;
    protected $dbTable;

    public function setDbDetails($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbDatabase)
    {
        $this->dbConnection = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbDatabase);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            throw new Exception('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

    public function setDbConnection($dbConnection)
    {
        $this->dbConnection = $dbConnection;
    }

    public function setDbTable($dbTable)
    {
        $this->dbTable = $dbTable;
    }

    public function open()
    {
        $limit = time() - (1800 * 24);
        $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM %s WHERE timestamp < %s", $this->dbTable, $limit);
        return $this->dbConnection->query($sql);
    }

    public function close()
    {
        return $this->dbConnection->close();
    }

    public function read($id)
    {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT data FROM %s WHERE id = '%s'", $this->dbTable, $this->dbConnection->escape_string($id));
        if ($result = $this->dbConnection->query($sql)) {
            if ($result->num_rows && $result->num_rows > 0) {
                $record = $result->fetch_assoc();
                return $record['data'];
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        $sql = sprintf("REPLACE INTO %s VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')",
            $this->dbTable,
            $this->dbConnection->escape_string($id),
            $this->dbConnection->escape_string($data),
            time());
        return $this->dbConnection->query($sql);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM %s WHERE `id` = '%s'", $this->dbTable, $this->dbConnection->escape_string($id));
        return $this->dbConnection->query($sql);
    }

    public function gc($max)
    {
        $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM %s WHERE `timestamp` < '%s'", $this->dbTable, time() - intval($max));
        return $this->dbConnection->query($sql);
    }
}
```

y se ejecuta asi:

```
session_set_save_handler(array($session, 'open'),
                         array($session, 'close'),
                         array($session, 'read'),
                         array($session, 'write'),
                         array($session, 'destroy'),
                         array($session, 'gc'));
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
@session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no hay incompatibilidades evidentes, solo algunas observaciones.

Debería extender desde `SessionHandlerInterface` como indica en los [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-set-save-handler.php):

```
class MySqlSessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

Entonces:

```
$sessionHandler = new MySqlSessionHandler(/*... configuraciones de conexion */);
session_set_save_handler($sessionHandler);
session_start();
```

Fíjate que `session_start();` no tiene @. Quizás el error está siendo suprimido.

Te recomiendo usar [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php) y [declaraciones de tipos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php)